# Java - Read page source from url does not work

Tags: java, url, connection, bufferedreader

I am using the code below to read page source from url. It works almost for all urls but not for this url and just returns the url itself.

```
public static String getURLSource(String url) throws IOException
{
    URL urlObject = new URL(url);
    URLConnection urlConnection = urlObject.openConnection();
    //urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");

    return toString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
}

private static String toString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
{
    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8")))
    {
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

What is the problem and how can I modify the code to work properly? Thanks.

Comment: What is the difference between working and not working URL?

Comment: Thanks @Jens . If it works properly, it should return the html content of the page.

Comment: Yes that is clear. But you say *It works almost for all urls *. So there must be differences between These and the not working URL

Comment: Thanks again @Jens , I don't know. It is exactly a part of my question.

Comment: This exception has been thrown --> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 1):

You must use a HttpsURLConnection, since it is https.

Comment: Thanks. I coded again using HttpsURLConnection. The code works for https://www.google.com but not for the url in my question!